# best Java code to control big heap memeory used (like 1G)

Tags: java, heap-memory

Currently, I need to write a Java program (don't care it function) just to use huge heap memory for testing.

writing a short java code which can exact control how much heap to be used will be quite useful .

Comment: Limit of RAM doesn't depend of java code, but options at runtime.

Comment: What I don't understand is why a low-quality question like this is coming from an established user, ***especially since you claim to be working at Oracle*** (from your profile). Possible profile hijack?

Comment: This is not how SO works. You first *try* something, then *compare* it to what you need get, and if they do not fit, you then ask a question, showing what you did, where it failed and how and what you would like to get.

Comment: Just make a 1GB text file or something and open it with your Java program.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: @cybermonkey on SO is very easy to get many points on beginners questions "why I have NullPointerException" and hard get high reputation on niche, low range specialistic framework. Hard times ;)

Comment: @JacekCz I know that, I've been here longer than you have & have 4x your rep.

Comment: @cybermonkey It is NOT that easy to write a simple program to use 1G memory, i am writing now, you need to calculate things, you need to avoid JVM doing unexpected  reduce memory for you.  it is NOT as easy like you thought to use exact 1G memory use an easiest program .    about Oracle, Oracle doen't only has java...

Comment: `private static final byte[] MemoryWaster = new byte[1_073_741_824];`, or maybe `new byte[1024][1_048_576]` to not require it all to be consecutive.

Comment: @BenXu I'm not saying that it's easy, I'm saying that *you*, who has experience with Java at *Oracle*, should be able to do this.

Comment: @cybermonkey yes,  i am able to do it using dozens of ways.  but  get  a perfect solution quickly is good, i don't think stackoverflow is only for things you can't do , but find  a good things that better than you can think is also good.

Comment: @ hata read file is too slow

Comment: @Andreas thanks , this seem quite good. checking now

Comment: @Blip try to use 4G+ memory to see if 64bit things works at special things..

Comment: may be , i am not expressed well in title, should be a "best" program to use 1G memory

Comment: ; @Andreas  thanks,   tried , 2 diamond byte array is quite good for such needs, and can use exactly memory needed  (use another for loop to create as much 2 diamond byte array as possible.)

Comment: "i am able to do it using dozens of ways" It's on you to prove it. Right now your question just looks like begging, with such phrases as "ASAP" and "pls help", which is especially unbecoming of someone at a big company like Oracle (as disliked as it is). That's not going to go over well at all. You may want to go back and read [ask] for help formulating a good question - this is not your first question and you should be fairly familiar with the asking process by now.

Comment: @all, i have removed my introduction with Oracle inside it .  I don't know why people care such things. Oracle is good, Oracle is bad.....

Comment: We expect questions from everyone to meet a certain quality standard regardless of their employment or social status. It's just incredibly unprofessional to say things like "pls help". You can choose whether or not to disclose your affiliation, but what matters most is that you try to improve your questions. If you don't do that, you risk losing the ability to ask questions in the future.

Comment: @ BoltClock already changed the question,and i think both question and answer has value.    It's common need such test to just use big heap meomory.   I use stackoverfow a lot, I search it first, when there is no answer, ask a question and i think i will help others in future

Comment: @BenXu You should know that 'best practice' questions are *also* off-topic here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quickly allocate 1 GB of memory:

```
byte[][] memoryWaster = new byte[1024][1_048_576];
```

See last test run below for successful allocation of **16 GB** of memory.

*Test program*

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
System.out.printf("total: %11d   max: %d%n", runtime.totalMemory(), runtime.maxMemory());
System.out.printf("used:  %11d%n", runtime.totalMemory() - runtime.freeMemory());
System.gc();
System.out.printf("gc:    %11d%n", runtime.totalMemory() - runtime.freeMemory());
byte[][] memoryWaster = new byte[1024][1_048_576];
memoryWaster[0][0] = 2; // prevent unused warning
System.out.printf("new[]: %11d%n", runtime.totalMemory() - runtime.freeMemory());
System.gc();
System.out.printf("gc:    %11d%n", runtime.totalMemory() - runtime.freeMemory());
memoryWaster = null;
System.out.printf("null:  %11d%n", runtime.totalMemory() - runtime.freeMemory());
System.gc();
System.out.printf("gc:    %11d%n", runtime.totalMemory() - runtime.freeMemory());
```

*Output* (Java 8, 32-bit):

```
// Java 1.8.0_51, 32-bit, no -Xmx given
total:    16252928   max: 259522560
used:       543288
gc:         349296
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at test.Test.main(Test.java:11)

// Java 1.8.0_51, 32-bit, -Xmx1200m
total:    16252928   max: 1216348160
used:       543288
gc:         349296
new[]:  1078435312
gc:     1078382592
null:   1078382592
gc:       15711288

// Java 1.8.0_51, 64-bit, no -Xmx given, 32 GB machine
total:   514850816   max: 7618953216
used:      5389872
gc:        2981048
new[]:  1074961632
gc:     1081175720
null:   1081175720
gc:       13027424

// Java 1.8.0_51, 64-bit, -Xmx1200m
total:   514850816   max: 1118830592
used:      5389872
gc:        2981048
new[]:  1077948560
gc:     1078944096
null:   1078944096
gc:        3501136

// Java 1.8.0_51, 64-bit, -Xmx20g, new byte[16384][1_048_576]
total:   514850816   max: 19088801792
used:      5389872
gc:        2981048
new[]: 17205604928
gc:    17205604928
null:  17205604928
gc:       26186032
```

Comment: thanks , just two  diamond array idea is enough for me.  which can control the exact size

Comment: `memoryWaster` the best identifier I have ever seen :)

Answer (score -2):

Creating such program is very simple, just create more object and do not let them garbage collect. One example is below.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class UseHugeRAM {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    int counter = 0;
    for (;;) {
        list.add("" + counter++);
    }
  }
}
```

You can very well bound for loop to some value so that it exits after creating these many string objects. For now this will simply exhaust the memory as not terminating. I hope it helps.

> In nutshell you are storing all the objects and not letting them garbage collect. That's something you should protect while building your application.

Comment: Why is some of the text in blockquotes? Are you quoting this from elsewhere?

Comment: Not sure how do you highlight something if not by the blockquotes?

Comment: Blockquotes are not for highlighting, they're for *quoting* text from elsewhere (implying you didn't write it yourself). Your text is just... text. There's nothing that needs to be highlighted. It's perfectly normal to have a series of paragraphs in English with no highlighting even if it's your own writing.

Comment: Al-right, i think i got the idea behind it, but still if you wanted to highlight something what is the option? If you wanted to refer something you have links too...So why to put something in blockquotes if not the highlighting of text is motto?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help but use very sparingly. Too much highlighting makes your post hard to read - sometimes, no highlighting is better than too much. Definitely blockquotes are an *incorrect* way of highlighting, though.

Comment: I hardly understand what exactly you mean by that, but there is no such rule mentioned in editing example. That may be your perspective to look at the various posts and answers, but for many of us we do definitely focus on the highlighted area under a post. Anyway that does not apply as a rule until it is mentioned as community standards.

Comment: @SandeepMandori Quote blocks are for *quoting* stuff.